# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'

Tags: android-studio

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.one.gnuinfo.abcd/com.one.gnuinfo.abcd.ViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

ViewActivity.java code:

```
package com.one.gnuinfo.abcd;

  import android.graphics.Color;
  import android.os.Build;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.widget.RatingBar;
  import android.widget.TextView;

     public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.noticeview);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String text = bundle.getString("item_text");

        TextView sc_t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        sc_t.setText(text);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {  
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#0BC904"));
        }

     RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
     TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contentview);
     TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contentview);
     TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timedateview);
     TextView textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inquiryview);
     bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     Float score = bundle.getFloat("score");
     String time = bundle.getString("time");
     String content = bundle.getString("content");
     String timestap = bundle.getString("timestap");
     String inquiry = bundle.getString("inquiry");
     ratingBar.setRating(score);
     textView1.setText(time);
     textView2.setText(content);
     textView3.setText(timestap);
     textView4.setText("inquiry "+inquiry);
       }
      }
```